# Debootstrap chroot Installation Error

Tags: 12.04, server, virtualization, chroot, xen

During initial installation (using both Network installation and CD ISO) of Ubuntu Server 12.04.1 LTS (64-bit) as a guest VM on XenServer 6.1 I'm getting this error:

```
Debootstrap warning
Warning: Failure trying to run: chroot /target dpkg --force-depends
--install /var/cache/apt/archives/debconf_1.5.42ubuntu1_all.deb
```

Any ideas?

Just tried the same ISO on VirtualBox and it errored in the same way, although on different packages: base_files_6.5ubuntu6.2_amd64.deb and base-passwd_3.5.24_amd64.deb

I'm redownloading and trying another ISO.

Comment: You should provide more information, like the specific command you are trying  to run and system information (architecture, ubuntu version, etc)

Comment: Indeed. Sorry. Updated.